# Rails performance loading entire table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance

I have a table that has thousands of entries. I am putting each entry into a "datatable" shown here: http://learning.aws.ipv4.ro/html/essential-tables.html

Basically when the page loads my controller is saying `@query = Table.all` so I can get each entry. Is this okay? Should I be concerned about performance issues when my table is very large?

Comment: Don't do that. In development we always start with a subset of the data, but if the code becomes useful there's a good likelihood that table can grow beyond your script's ability to hold it all in memory causing your system to crash, to DOS itself, to clog the network, to slow the database server, and/or combinations of the above. Scalability should always be a consideration when you're reading data, whether it's from a file or a database, since they can contain more information than you have RAM in your machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you generally should be concerned about loading too much data at once.

For situations where it makes sense (probably most), consider adding pagination. The [Kaminari gem](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari) is my favorite for such purposes.

Comment: But doesnt this still load all the data at once? `@posts = Post.paginate(:page => params[:page])`

Comment: No, calling `paginate` will scope the query using `LIMIT` syntax based on page number and number of records to load for the page.

Comment: So it will do another query whenever you go to page 2 for example?

Comment: Yes, it will. I suggest installing the gem and playing around with it in the Rails console to see what it does.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any opinion on Kaminari vs will paginate gem?

Comment: When evaluating gems, I look at the amount of complexity I'm introducing into my app, whether or not it provides the functionality I'm looking for, and when it was last updated. For the last of my criteria: will_paginate was last updated Jun 28, 2014, and Kaminari was last updated Jun 14, 2015. Hmm... :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, large data is going to make the site very slow for the user. Alternative to the Kaminari gem is [Will Paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate)